# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinauto-0.6.3 in windows 10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install python library pywinauto-0.6.3 but m getting error could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinauto-0.6.3(from versions:)
I am using windows 10.Is any one there who faced same issue please help in in this.

Comment: What command are you using to install it? Are you actually using the `-` in package name?

Comment: m using command py -m pip install pywinauto-0.6.3 and m using python 3.6.3

Comment: You don't use `-` to specify a version number, use `==`.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me

Comment: @jordanm please post it as an answer.